# Simple javascript prototype issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to attach an onclick function to every a tag.

I have

```
task.prototype.init=function(){  
        for (value in obj){
            var Link=document.createElement('a');
                Link.innerHTML='click';
                Link.id=value;   //I want to get the value
                Link.href='#'
                Link.onclick=this.changeName;
                document.body.appendChild(Link);
         }
}

task.prototype.changeName=function(){  

        //I want to get the clicked element id and I am not sure how to do it. 

    return false;
    }
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: What is this `obj` and where it is defined?

Comment: what is `obj`? what is `task`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dWPCS/2/

In your event handler `changeName`the `this` references to the element. So `this.id`returns the value you want.

Comment: Confusing. Don't do this. Methods are expected to be called in the context of the corresponding instance.

Comment: @katspaugh I'm providing a solution. It may not be the perfect one but in the real world, no one enters code into a beauty contest.

Comment: TJ., it isn't about beauty. It's about maintainability. The guy you'd provided the solution to was immediately confused and asked [a follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996794/javascript-prototype-this-issue).

Answer (score 1):

Inside an event handler, `this` is the object that created the event, so this should work:

```
task.prototype.changeName=function() { alert(this.id); };
```