# JavaScript prototype 'this' issue

Tags: javascript

This is a follow up question from my last question.

[Simple javascript prototype issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996187/simple-javascript-prototype-issue)

I am a bit new using JavaScript `prototype` so sorry for the second post.

I want to assign the clicked element `id` to the `this.name` array.

```
task.prototype.init=function(){  
      this.name=[];  //this.name array has to be defined here

        for (var i; i<5; i++){
            var Link=document.createElement('a');
                Link.innerHTML='click';
                Link.id=value[i];   //I want to assign the value to the this.name array
                Link.href='#'
                Link.onclick=this.changeName;
                document.body.appendChild(Link);
         }
}
task.prototype.changeName=function(){  

     //How do I push the this.id to the property this.name?

     //the code below won't work because this refer to the <a> element. 
     this.name.push(this.id);     

    return false;
    }
```

Any tips for the task?

Comment: Don't use CapitalCase for regular variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Callback Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope) and [addEventListener and the scope of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803195/addeventlistener-and-the-scope-of-this) and many others.

Comment: I think 'name' is actually reserved as well.`callee: function () {
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""`

Comment: Here's an example without using name: http://jsfiddle.net/kThM2/4/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your prototype is okay, the problem is that `this` on event handlers is always the element that caused the event to be triggered. [In JavaScript, the value of `this` inside a function depends on how the function is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

If you want `this` to be bound to a certain value, you can create a bound function with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var newChangeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
Link.onclick = newChangeName;
```

Note however that `bind` is IE9+ only. A workaround would be:

```
var that = this;
Link.onclick = function() {
    that.changeName();
};
```

(Style note: I'd use `link` instead of `Link`; the convention in js is to leave uppercase initials to constructors).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the desired `this` for the `changeName` callback:

```
Link.onclick=this.changeName.bind(this);
```