# Using 'this' inside a callback inside an object literal

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript prototype ‘this’ issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996794/javascript-prototype-this-issue)

I have an event listener which of course calls a method on an event.  This method tries unsuccessfully to hold a reference to the holding objects this so that it can access other properties of the object.

There is a single comment denoting where the behavior is not understood.  this_hold.Name is not accessible there as I thought it would be.

```
/*MUserExist
**
**
**
*/
$A.module({
    Name: 'MUserExist',
    S: {
        ClientStorage: SClientStorage,
        ComMessage: SComMessage,
        ComText: SComText,
        DynSma: SDynSma,
        DynTwe: SDynTwe,
        DynArc: SDynArc,
        AniMorphLabel: SAniMorphLabel,
        AniFlipPage: SAniFlipPage
    },
    E: {
        but: $A('#ue_but')[0],
        text: $A('#ue_go')[0],
        form: $A('#ue_fo')[0],
        check: $A('#ue_check')[0]
    },
    J: {
        box: $('#ue_box')
    },
    init: function () {
        var pipe = {},
            this_hold = this;
        this.J.box.draggable();
        this.E.but.addEventListener("click", function () {
            pipe = $A.definePipe(this_hold.Name);
            $A.machine(pipe);
        }, false);
        this.E.text.addEventListener("keypress", this.enter, false);
        this.S.AniMorphLabel.run(["ue_email",
                                  "ue_email_lab",
                                  "ue_go",
                                  "ue_pass_lab"
                                 ]);
    },
    enter: function (event) {
        var pipe = {},
            this_hold = this;
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            pipe = $A.definePipe(this_hold.Name); // fails here what does 'this' point to?
            $A.machine(pipe);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    pre: function (pipe) {
        var form_elements = this.E.form.elements,
            text_object = new this.S.ComText(form_elements);
        pipe.enter = this.enter;
        if ($A.Un.get('load') === '1') {
            if (!text_object.checkFull()) {
                pipe.type = 'empty';
                return this.S.ComMessage.message(pipe);
            }
            if (!text_object.checkPattern('email')) {
                pipe.type = 'email';
                return this.S.ComMessage.message(pipe);
            }
            if (!text_object.checkPattern('pass')) {
                pipe.type = 'pass';
                return this.S.ComMessage.message(pipe);
            }
        }
        pipe.page = text_object.getArray();
        pipe.proceed = true;
        pipe.page.remember = this.E.check.checked;
        return pipe;
    },
    post : function (pipe) {
        if (pipe.proceed === true) {
            this.S.ComMessage.resetView('ue_email');
            this.S.ComMessage.resetView('ue_go');
            this.S.ClientStorage.setAll(pipe.server.smalls);
            this.S.DynSma.run(pipe.server.smalls);
            this.S.DynArc.run(pipe.server.arcmarks);
            this.S.DynTwe.run(pipe.server.tweets);
            this.S.AniFlipPage.run('ma');
        } else {
            return this.S.ComMessage.message(pipe);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check the possible dupe link, I just answered a very similar question.

Comment: A simple `console.log(this)` can answer your question and you didn't try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is the DOM object that generated the event.  It is NOT your javascript object.

When you pass `this.enter` as the method for the event handler, the method `enter` does not stay bound to your object.  If you want that to happen, you have to change your code to cause that to happen by doing something like this:

```
// save local copy of my object so I can refer to it in
// the anonymous function
var obj = this;
this.E.text.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {obj.enter(event)}, false);
```

It is important to remember that `this` is set by the caller of a method/function.  In this case the caller of the event handler is the event sub-system in the browser.  It does not know what your object is and it's designed behavior is to set `this` to the DOM object that caused the event.  So, if you want to call your obj.enter method, you can't just pass `enter` as the event handler.  Instead, you make a separate function that gets called as the event handler and you then call `obj.enter()` from that using your object as the base so that `this` gets set correctly.

Another solution would be to use `.bind()` which also creates a stub function that binds the right `this` to a function call, but I don't use `.bind()` myself because it doesn't work in all older browsers.

Comment: @pure_code - note I just made one quick correction in the code.

Comment: would using apply() here be applicable at all?....and this works.

Comment: @pure_code - `.apply()` will also set the `this` pointer, but is not required here because you have an object with a method and `obj.method()` sets `this` for you in a more readable fashion.  But, yes you could use `enter.apply(obj, arguments)` if you wanted in the same stub function.  I just find that less readable than the code I suggested.

Comment: I can't use an un-named function because I need to remove the eventListener for 2000 msec and then add it back...for this you need a reference to the callback function.

Comment: Does apply return a function reference so I can use it directly for the callback `..("keypress, enter.apply(obj, arguments), false);`

Comment: @pure_code - No.  `.apply()` calls the function immediately.  `.bind()` returns a reference.

Comment: bind() seems like a more succinct solution?

Answer (score 2):

`this` likely points to the DOM node from which the event was triggered. Have you tried writing `this` to the console to inspect it?

```
console.log(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change how the event is being bound

```
this.E.text.addEventListener("keypress", this.enter, false);
```

to

```
var that = this;
this.E.text.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  that.enter(event);
}, false);
```